# jquery validation plugin is not working for all fields

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have this code and when i try to click submit, it doesn't validate any fields...
 i don't know how to solve this.. pls help with this.. thanks in advance..  all the fields in the form are required. I have to validate only by using jquery validation plugin....

```
<div>
    <form name="signUp" id="registerationForm">
         <h3> Sign Up For Free </h3>
        <label class="c1" for="usrEmail">User Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="usrEmail">
        <label class="c1" for="usrName">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="usrName">
        <label class="c1" for="pwd">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd">
        <label class="c2">I AM A</label>
        <label class="c2">
            <input type="radio" value="DESIGNER" name="position">DESIGNER</label>
        <label class="c2">
            <input type="radio" name="position" value="DEVELOPER">DEVELOPER</label>
        <label class="c2">
            <input type="radio" name="position" value="NEITHER, I JUST HAVE IDEAS">NEITHER, I JUST HAVE IDEAS</label>
        <label class="c2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="agreements">I Have Read and Agree to the <span style="color:#097CA2"> Terms of Service </span> 
        </label>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="sign_up" value="SIGN UP NOW">
    </form>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#registerationForm').validate({
        rules: {
            usrEmail: {
                required: "true",
                email: "true"
            },
            usrName: "required",
            pwd: {
                pwd: "required",
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 18
            },
            terms: "required",
            position: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            usrEmail: "Please enter a valid email address",
            usrName: "Your Name is needed. Please enter it",
            pwd: {
                required: "please provide a password",
                minlength: "password must be minimum of 5 characters"
            },
            position: "Please select any position",
            terms: "please accept our policy"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where is your code to trigger the validation?

Comment: right now you are using check as user type, to make it check on click use `$('.submit').click function(){ return false; if($(form).valid()) then submit` and if it is not validating at all then check your syntax

Comment: @ScottSelby i think you have to scroll to see the jquery code

Comment: @vico tried.. also checked all syntax.. its not validating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your Javascript.

1. All `true` attributes need to be without quotes.
2. First attribute in `pwd` should be `required: true` not `pwd: "required"`.

Here is corrected code:

```
<div>
    <form name="signUp" id="registerationForm">
         <h3> Sign Up For Free </h3>
        <label class="c1" for="usrEmail">User Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="usrEmail">
        <label class="c1" for="usrName">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="usrName">
        <label class="c1" for="pwd">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd">
        <label class="c2">I AM A</label>
        <label class="c2">
            <input type="radio" value="DESIGNER" name="position">DESIGNER</label>
        <label class="c2">
            <input type="radio" name="position" value="DEVELOPER">DEVELOPER</label>
        <label class="c2">
            <input type="radio" name="position" value="NEITHER, I JUST HAVE IDEAS">NEITHER, I JUST HAVE IDEAS</label>
        <label class="c2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="agreements">I Have Read and Agree to the <span style="color:#097CA2"> Terms of Service </span> 
        </label>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="sign_up" value="SIGN UP NOW">
    </form>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#registerationForm').validate({
        rules: {
            usrEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            usrName: "required",
            pwd: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 18
            },
            terms: "required",
            position: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            usrEmail: "Please enter a valid email address",
            usrName: "Your Name is needed. Please enter it",
            pwd: {
                required: "please provide a password",
                minlength: "password must be minimum of 5 characters"
            },
            position: "Please select any position",
            terms: "please accept our policy"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is the right answer. [Tested and working demo of the same](http://jsfiddle.net/XtVNL/)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the quotes. write true instead of writing "true"

Answer (score 0):

I think that plugin looks for `IDs`.

Try adding the Id attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="usrEmail" id="usrEmail">
```